# How to force reasonable execution plan for query with LIKE statement?

Tags: sql-server

When creating ad-hoc queries to look for information in a table I have run into this issue over and over.

Let's say I have a table with a million records with fields id - int, createddatetime - timestamp, category - varchar(50) and content - varchar(max). I want to find all records in the last day that have a certain string in the content field. If I create a query like this...

```
select *
from table
where createddatetime > '2018-1-31'
    and content like '%something%'
```

it may complete in a second because in the last day there may only be 100 records so the LIKE clause is only operating on a small number of records

However if I add one more item to the where clause...

```
select *
from table
where createddatetime > '2018-1-31'
    and content like '%something%'
    and category = 'testing'
```

then it could take many minutes to complete while locking up the table.

It appears to be changing from performing all the straight forward WHERE clause items first and then the LIKE on the limited set of records, over to having the LIKE clause first. There are even times where there are multiple LIKE statements and adding one more causes the query to go from a split second to minutes.

The only solutions I've found are to either generate an intermediate table (maybe temp tables would work), insert records based on the basic WHERE clause items, then run a separate query to filter by one or more LIKE statements. I've tried various JOIN and CTE approaches which usually have no improvement. Alternatively CHARINDEX also appears to work though difficult to use if trying to convert the logic of multiple LIKE statements.

Is there any hint or something that can be placed in the query statement to tell sql server to wait until records are filtered by the basic WHERE clause items before filtering by the LIKE?

---

I actually just tried this approach and it had the same issue...

```
select *
from (
    select *, charindex('something', content) as found
    from bounce
    where createddatetime > '2018-1-31'
) t
where found > 0
```

while the subquery independently returns in a couple seconds, the overall query just never returns. Why is this so bad

Comment: If the `content` are huge texts, I believe you should perhaps take a look at full-text indexing... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879306(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Have you looked at the actual execution plans of the two queries?   Updated statistics?

Comment: How many rows do you have per day on average? How many distinct categories do you have, and is this always populated? Do you have an index that covers those three columns (and do you really need `SELECT *` or could you use a subset of columns)?

Comment: These are all great comments and questions. However it doesn't answer the underlying issue. Why given a query that for example returns a dozen records would a LIKE statement that should operate over those dozen cause the query to take 100x longer to return.

Comment: I can't even test this situation any more because after trying various query variations my example is now returning in a reasonable amount of time, without doing anything like rebuilding indexes or updating statistics. I was simply trying to see execution plans and now everything is fine. This is an issue that comes up every few months on different tables so it is a more general question than how to optimize a query which previous comments are related to.

Comment: We cannot KNOW what the issue is from a description like the one you have provided, we need more information.  Specifically, can you provide actual execution plans for both the fast and slow executions?  Once we get a look at them we will have some good information to work with.

Comment: Because your LIKE statement is nonSARGable due to the leading wildcard. You have removed the ability to utilize an index to find rows with that. The where predicates do not filter in order, as such just because you put the LIKE at the end of your query does not mean that is how the engine will process them.

Comment: @SeanLange where clauses are not run in order but they are not run in a random order. What I'm trying to understand is why given an efficient query that returns a small number of records would the query analyzer opt to have the LIKE clause come first (edit: which based on the speed appears to be what is happening since I can't see the slow execution plan now)

Comment: Also, what indexes are on that table?

Comment: Again, the crux of the issue is SARGability. You can't short circuit where predicates in a single query which is what you seem to be asking about.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for that term as I have not seen it before. Generates a lot of material to read when searched

Comment: You can't force the order of `WHERE` clause evaluation like you can for joins. You could however, if you see consistency in the speed increase, break it into two queries with one filling a table variable / temporary table (depending on how much rows you're expecting) and the other doing another filtering on top of it.

Comment: Did you try updating statistics?

Comment: Getting more information ***does*** help answer the underlying issue. Don't brush questions away just because ***you*** don't see the link.

Comment: @AaronBertrand good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not fancy, but I've had better luck with temp tables than nested select statements... It will isolate the first data set, and then you can select just from that. If you're looking for quick and dirty, which usually serves my purposes for ad-hoc, this may help. If this is a permanent stored proc, the indexing suggestions may serve you better in the long run.

```
select *
into #like
from table
where createddatetime > '2018-1-31'
    and content like '%something%'

select * 
from #like 
where category = 'testing'
```

Comment: this is the only thing I have found to work consistently

Comment: Awesome! Best of luck!